# How to link the function of a button to a single marker of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, google-maps-markers, each

I have an array with 20 element like this:

they are showed on the map with a green marker, but I want that when i click on the button and some property are respected, the marker turns red.
The problem is that when i change the color, every marker turns red and not only one. So, how can I set the function for only one element based on property?

```
const array = [
{ text: "something1",
  coordinates: "something2"
},
...
];

function do(){
//what the function should do
}
```

Comment: Maybe add a new field for each marker, isClicked: boolean and when you click set it to true? In this way you can have the state of all the markers and you can know which is clicked or not

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a property e.g. colour for every object in your array:

```
array .forEach(obj => obj.color = 'green')
```

Then in your function, add a condition to change the 'green' property to 'red' only for objects that are clicked

Comment: sadly it doesn't work.. I want to insert the code so it can be more understandable but it's so long.. by the way, i have this markers on map. When i click on the marker, it shows up a popup with info and a button. When the button is clicked, the marker should turn red, but every marker turns red.

Comment: if(booking === "1h"){
mybtn.disabled = true;
window.confirm();                                                                                          
setTimeout(() => {
mybtn.disabled = false;
}, "5000");
stazioni.map(item => {
marker = new L.marker(item.coordinates, {icon: redMarker})
.bindPopup()
.openPopup();
marker.addTo(map);
});
setTimeout(() => {
stazioni.map(item => {
 marker = new L.marker(item.coordinates, {icon: greenMarker})
.bindPopup()
.openPopup();
marker.addTo(map);
});
}, "5000");                       
}

Comment: The code it's like this (it's in the previous comment)
The code works and i understand why it shows all red, because with stazioni.map(item ... ) i select every item in the array, but i don't know how to apply the effect of the function on only one item of the array..

Comment: and what is in stazioni?
You should assign ids to mybtns and in your map, do the {icon: redMarker} only for buttons with the id as clicked one

Comment: This is what is in stazioni (there are 20 like them) and they are point on the map.
const stazioni = [
{
text: "Via Giovanni Giolitti, 143, 00185 Roma (RM)",
coordinates: [41.89947045325958, 12.502756543946065]
},
]

i have an ID for mybtn, but it's unique for all the markers.
I thought that a solution coud be like

if mybtn clicked, get marker coordinates which was clicked and set marker red
but i don't know if it's possible doing this